# How to tell SQL Server not to warn on temp table usage in a [sub] procedure?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

What I have is a stored procedure (**A**) that creates a temp table (**T**) and invokes another procedure (**B**). **B** inserts into **T**, but since it was created in **A**, the build warns me that **T** is unknown in **B**. If code makes more sense to you then here it is:

```
BEGIN TRAN
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.B
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1)
    INSERT INTO #T VALUES (0)
    INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1)
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.A
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #T
    (
        Dummy BIT
    )
    EXEC dbo.B
    SELECT * from #T
END
GO
EXEC dbo.A

ROLLBACK
```

Is there a way I can direct Visual Studio not to warn me about this? I'm hoping there's something like ReSharper comments that can tell it to ignore this issue.

I know the alternative would be to add a `if not exists, create T` script, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: It's not a SQL Server warning - it's a Visual Studio one.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I think it's actually an SSDT warning. It shows in Management Studio as well as warning in the Visual Studio build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend changing procedure **B** to return records. Then insert the records into the temp table with a `EXEC... INSERT` statement like this:

```
BEGIN TRAN
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.B
AS
BEGIN
    Select 1
    Union All Select 0
    Union All Select 1
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.A
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #T
    (
        Dummy BIT
    )
    EXEC dbo.B
    INSERT #T

    SELECT * from #T
END
GO
EXEC dbo.A

ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 1):

Try tossing in the following

```
IF 1 = 0
CREATE TABLE #T (Dummy BIT)
```

Comment: This will work, but I could never agree with putting `IF 1 = 0` into a program simply to avoid a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

Replace the call to B with the actual code.  In other words, instead of

```
 exec dbo.B
```

Use the actual code of B:

```
INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO #T VALUES (0)
INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1)
```

1. In B, you could replace the code that uses #T with dynamic SQL.  That will not warn when B is compiled.
2. You could convert #T into a permanent table.

Otherwise, no, I don't think there is a way to turn off this warning.  However, the warning is harmless.

Note that you would not get this warning if you used a table-valued parameter, but since those must be declared READONLY, I assumed that this is not an option for use in B.